# Как принять результат работы скрипта php на сервере?

Tags: android, php, java, jpeg

Есть скрипт написанный на PHP, который считает количество картинок jpg в директориях на сервере (принимает значение $_GET["имя папки"]).

```
<?php
    $path = $_GET["path"]; // название папки в той же директории, что и файл
    $dir = opendir ("$path"); // открываем директорию
    $i = 0; // создаём переменную для цикла
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {

    // ниже указываем расширение файла. Вместо jpg выбираете нужный
          if (strpos($file, '.jpg', 1) ) {
          $i++;
      }
    }

    $total = ($i - 1)/2;
    echo($total);
?>
```

Каким образом я могу получить результат (не JSON надеюсь) на приемной стороне?

Comment: А гугл отказался искать? Сказал, что это слишком просто?    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android+get+text+from+url

Comment: Получилось, используя AsyncTask, в методе doInBackground которого нашел num (ответ скрипта):
DefaultHttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://"); // скрипт
HttpResponse httpResponse = Client.execute(httpPost);
int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
num = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
<?
$path = safe($_GET['path']); // Всякие проверки на безопасность !Никогда не доверяй входным данным!
$count = count(glob($path . '*.jpg'));

print json_encode(['type' => 'jpg', 'count' => $count]);
```

По адресу скрипта заходишь с нужным параметром и получаешь JSON-кодированные данные (можно по разному кодировать, сериализировать, etc - зависит от ситуации).
P. S. Мне нравится такой вариант: `<? print json_encode(['type' => 'jpg', 'count' => count(glob(safe($_GET['path']) . '*.jpg'))]);`, хотя это хардкор :)

Comment: Действительно, проще без JSON тут...